# called library procedure is running in infinity cycle on gnu/linux

Tags: c, gcc

I've got an library which must read data from sqlite database by calling

```
extern int read(char** argv, int argc); // from header
```

it must process:

```
int read(char** argv, int argc) {
    char* lineborder1;
    char* lineborder2;
    char* spaces1;
    char* spaces2;
    int maxl2 = 0, maxl1 = 0;
    int i, maxi1, maxi2;
    if (prelude() == -1) return -1;
    // etc...
```

where prelude is inner procedure for sqlite connection:

```
int prelude() {
    timefile = 0;
    f = NULL;
#ifndef WIN32
    char* temp = (char*)calloc(200, sizeof(char));
#endif
    queries = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * q_cnt);
    for (x = 0; x < q_cnt; x++) {
        queries[x] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * q_size);
        }
#ifdef WIN32
    retval = sqlite3_open("todo.db3", &handle);
#else
    home = (char*)getenv("HOME");
    strcpy(temp, home);
    retval = sqlite3_open(strcat(temp, "/.todo.db3"), &handle);
    free(temp);
#endif
    if (retval) {
        printf("Database connection failed\n\r");
        return -1;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

whole source is here : [bitbucket: ctodo.c](https://bitbucket.org/Cynede/ctodo/src/42629babb8b0362f08f43918ee331bb6371d4e82/ctodo.c?at=default)

I call this read from my application:

```
else if ((strcmp(argv[1], "read") == 0) || (strcmp(argv[1], "r") == 0)) {
    return read(argv, argc);
```

but getting infinity cycle of this `read` call:

```
>>./todo r
Database connection failed
Database connection failed
Database connection failed
.... etc
```

here is how do I build it:

```
gcc -I . -c -o todo.a ctodo.c -lsqlite3 -O3
gcc -I . -o todo cctodo.c -lsqlite3 -O3 todo.a
```

`help` or `version` calls wrok fine and read works fine on windows, something specific to my linux build is here but I can't find a bug so far. what could call this `read` to run in infinity cycle like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read` function is defined in `libc.so`, and used to, you know, read data.

It is exceedingly likely that `sqlite3_open()` calls it.

By introducing your own function called `read()`, you've made your program enter infinite loop. If you wait long enough, your program will run out of stack and crash.

Doctor, it hurts when I do that. Well, don't do that :-)

Comment: oh, great ) I must to remember to use prefix naming for library api :P https://bitbucket.org/Cynede/ctodo/changeset/6168a9f19ff055baa18001ea7c646836 ( but windows compier works fine with it :D )